# Is a 1-form locally expressible as $dx$?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Given a 1-form $\alpha$ which is non-zero at every point of a manifold $M^n$, is it true that locally I can express the form as $dx$? (that is around each point there is a coordinate neighborhood such that $\alpha$ has that form). 
I think this is false because then the form will be closed in every neighborhood and hence closed.

The problem that I have is the following reasoning:
at a point $p$ in the manifold, extend $\alpha_p$ to a basis of the cotangent space at $p$, as being linearly independent is an open condition, that implies that I can extend it to $n$ (I guess smooth) sections of the cotangent bundle linearly independent at each point of a neighborhood of $p$. Now on each point of this neighborhood take the dual basis of tangent vectors, this will produce (I guess smooth) $n$ vector fields on this neighborhood, where the dual of $\alpha$ can be written in another coordinate system as $\partial/\partial x$ and therefore $\alpha$ as $dx$.

I think the first guess is correct but not sure about the second one, can someone explain it to me? thanks

Comment: A differential form is locally exact if and only if it is closed.

Answer (score 1):

The flaw in your argument is as follows: these $n$ vector fields do not define a coordinate system (they are not $\partial/\partial x_j$ for any coordinate system) in general.

Well, let us try an example. Assume $n=2$, $M^n=R^2$, $\alpha=f(x_2)dx_1$, where $f(x_2)$ does not vanish and $f'(x_2)$ is not zero identically. Then $d\alpha=-f'(x_2)dx_1\wedge dx_2\ne0$. Let as extend $\alpha$ to a basis of the cotangent space at each point:
$$
 \alpha_1=\alpha=f(x_2)dx_1,\quad \alpha_2=dx_2.
$$
It is easy to find the dual basis of tangent vectors at every point; we obtain the vector fields
$$
 V_1=\frac 1{f(x_2)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1},\quad V_2=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}.
$$
The new coordinate $t$ along tha trajectories of $V_1$ is $t=f(x_2)(x_1-g(x_2))$, where $g$ is an arbitrary function. But $dt\ne\alpha$, sorry.

Comment: True, but I can always find and integral curve of one of them, in this case of the one corresponding to the dual of $\alpha$. So every point will have a coordinate neighborhood in which the first coordinate gives the dual of $\alpha$. I´m not saying the same thing holds for all the others at once.

Comment: I am afraid this is another flaw... The derivative $\partial f/\partial x_1$ depends not only on what $x_1$ is, but also on what you take for $x_2,\dots,x_n$.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your last comment. What I meant is that in  that coordinate neighbourhood $(x_1,...,x_n)$, the dual of $\alpha$ is a vector field that can be represented as $\partial/\partial x_1$ (the rest of the vector fields that I constructed I agree won't be necessarily of the form $\partial/\partial x_i$ but I don't need that for my argument.

Comment: Another quick way to see this is that if vector fields define a coordinate system, then a necessary condition is that for any $X_i, X_j$ in the system of vector fields, we must have that $X_i(X_j(f)) = X_j(X_i(f))$ for all smooth $f$ or more concisely $[X_i, X_j] = 0$. This represents the fact that mixed partials don't change when we change order. Your construction definitely doesn't guarantee this wont happen.

Answer (score 1):

It's clearly necessary for $\alpha$ to be closed. Since the property in question is local, it's sufficient to prove the result for $M = \mathbb{R}^n$. Choose an arbitrary point $p\in M$. Since $M$ is contractible, we have $\alpha = df$ for some $f\in C^\infty(M)$. Since $\alpha(p)\not = 0$, there exists by the constant rank theorem some coordinates $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ on a neighborhood $U$ centered at $p$ with $f(x_1, \dots, x_n) = x_1$. Thus $\alpha = dx_1$ on $U$.